# Powershell Rename file based on SQL query

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-server-2012

We take a lot of photograph's for product imagery . I have found a piece of software that will read a Barcode embeded in the image and rename the Image to the Barcode within the image , what i now want to do is rename the File again with the Productid using powershell with an SQL query within ,

```
    declare @$CliRef nvarchar(max)
set @$CliRef = '5015807416980'

Select   convert(nvarchar(max), productid) as ID FROM products WHERE products.Barcode = @$CliRef
```

I Found a Powershell script online but I must be doing something wrong as its renaming the file blank rather than a productid , I'm really new to Powershell so a little stuck so any help appreciated

```
    $Database = "training"
$Server = "ART-WM01"

##Not sure i need this bit 

function Select-Info($CliRef) 
   {

  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
$SqlConnection.Open()

    $conn.open()
    $query = “Select convert(varchar,producdid )as ID FROM products WHERE barcode = '$CliRef'”
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
    $cmd.connection = $SqlConnection
    $cmd.commandtext = $query
    $result = $cmd.executenonquery()
    $SqlConnection.Close()

    return $query
    }

## Return ID from Database
 function Return-Info($CliRef)
{

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.commandtext = “Select convert(varchar, productid) as ID FROM products WHERE barcode = '$CliRef'”
$cmd.connection = $SqlConnection
$result = $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()

return $result

}

 ## Collect the image names
 $FiNms = Get-ChildItem C:\JJC\Test_Dump -Name

 ## Loop through each Image name
 foreach ($FiNm in $FiNms)

{

 ## Variable for current File path
 $file = “C:\JJC\Test_Dump\” + $FiNm
 ##  Variable for new File path
 $newFile = “C:\JJC\Test_Dump\renamed” + $FiNm

$ID = Return-Info $FiNm

$ID = $ID + “.tiff”

##Copy-Item $file -Destination $newFile 

##Copy-Item $file -Destination = “C:\JJC\\Test_Dump\renamed\”
Rename-Item $file $ID -force

}
```

[image]

Comment: From the code you posted, it appears that your SQL query may not be returning the result you expect. Have you tried just executing the query and seeing what it returns? Also, your query uses a database built-in function, namely `convert`. Built-in functions a not part of standard SQL so it would probably help people to answer your question if you stated what DBMS you are using.

Comment: HI , using MSBD 2012 , I checked the SQL and seems to be OK? ,although i had a typo ,but the output is still a unnamed file

Comment: As sidenote: do yourself a favor and replace all those ugly curly 'smart-quotes' with straight ones. In Word they may look nice, but in code, the are bad.